# Running Xcode on Chrome OS

Tags: xcode, google-chrome, xcode6

**Is there any way that I can run Xcode or even OS X on my computer**

***see my specs of my PC [About My Chrome OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EbKIx.png)***

Thanks alot,
 *(I'll appreciate any answer)!*

Comment: This is not really a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not legally... But you could install Linux on your Chromebook, and code in a different language, or use CodeAnywhere (or anouther online IDE like it) to write in many other languages.

Comment: Can you suggest me some of online IDE for ios development?

Comment: [CodeAnywhere](https://codeanywhere.com/) or [Cloud9](//c9.io) are some different options, choose the one the works best for you :)

Comment: You are welcome, click the checkmark to tell everyone that this answer helped you :)

Comment: any online ide for ios development?

Comment: No, XCode is the only IDE with all the feature you would most likely want (as a first time dev). Maybe write a web app instead? Then your app will also work on Android or other phones, too.

Comment: are you a apple developer (beginner)?

Comment: I haven't really made an app (I have played around with Swift), nor do I work for Apple.